# HttpWebRequest works faster with Fiddler running

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I have made some test sending a request to http://www.google.com

With fiddler running, average response time is 0.02s per request

Without fiddler running, average response time is 0.9s pre request.

HUGE differences.

```
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var wrGeturl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
            wrGeturl.KeepAlive = true;
            wrGeturl.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate,sdch");
            wrGeturl.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
            wrGeturl.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            wrGeturl.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            using (var reqStream = wrGeturl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (reqStream != null)
                {
                    var webPage = new StreamReader(reqStream).ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Time: " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

Its a very basic code without any logic behind it, so I dont get it.

I looked at other posts and saw I have to set the KeepAlive property to TRUE, I've done that, but nothing changes.

Any idea what could this weird issue be?

Comment: Have you tried setting `Proxy` to null ?

Comment: Yes, doesnt change anything.

Comment: Are you issuing these requests in a loop, or only once? If in a loop, how fast is EACH request? The most common source of such a result would be failure of `Keep-Alive` but it *looks* like you've enabled that properly, and that you're properly disposing of the object returned by GetResponseStream. Have you looked in System.Net logs or WireShark/Netmon to see if you're getting connection reuse?